# How to save application log external card android

Tags: android, logging, logcat, android-logcat

I have read many threads in the form on how to save log file in SD card, but I am **confused** reading so many threads :(

Can anyone send me a piece of code on how to save logs.txt for:

1. My own application exception/ sysout only
2. Log all exceptions while not connected to eclipse computer to some 
   location and all error happened during run time by user.

Please help.

Comment: This is generally not a good idea. The SD card doesn't enforce application, so a malicious app could scan through those log files and potentially get sensitive about the user. (From experience, logs often contain sensitive information.) You're better off using a service like Splunk Mint or Crittercism, which stores the logs on a secure server.

Comment: hi..this is for testing purpose only...i will remove those lines before making apk...